# Python Selenium Pop-up selection page for website. How can I select/highlight multiple different values on a pop-up?

Tags: python, html, selenium, popup

To preface, I've only been experimenting with Python for 7-8 months so im still quite the novice. I'm working on a project when I'm able to navigate through an insurance website (progressive) and move on to the quote creation process.

I'm stuck on this pop-up and want it to select Auto + Home(HO3) before clicking "Start Quote"

The code I have so far up to the pop-up:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\domin\\Downloads\\chromedriver') 
driver.get('https://www.foragentsonly.com/login/')
driver.find_element_by_id('user1').send_keys('pass') 
driver.find_element_by_id('password1').send_keys('user')
driver.find_element_by_id('image1').click()
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('QuoteStateList')) 
select.select_by_visible_text('Illinois')
driver.find_element_by_id('selectProductButton').click()
```

[Image of Pop-Up and inspect element details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xmxan.png)

Any and all help/recommendations are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Right now I don't have time to test your code but it is quite likely that the page if not fully loaded. You should always use some [waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to ensure that the DOM element you are expecting is available. Do you have a specific error reported by Python ?

Comment: @Anonymous the code included all runs without errors and works up until the pop-up box. I tried finding the elements by ID on the pop up but it doesn’t do anything when executed. My question is how can I click “Auto” and then click “Start Quote” on this pop up. Maybe that adds a bit more context.

Comment: @Anonymous I added the image of the pop up in the post with inspect element details

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot test this page without a login. But I think you are going too fast (could be one problem among others). After doing the login should wait until the DOM elements expected are available. But I don't see in your code where you are clicking on `Auto` and `Home`. For example to select `Home` you should normally address the tag `<span class="prod-desc">Home H03</span>` and use `click` I guess.

Comment: haven't tested your code yet, but by reading it:"driver.find_element_by_id('user1').send_keys('pass') ", seem slike should be :driver.find_element_by_id('user1').send_keys('user') and same for password. maybe you invereted both: did you invert password for username and vice versa ?

Comment: @NonoLondon I just put in place holders for the real credentials, I don’t want to put out those values for obvious reasons which makes it hard to test the code. However the code runs through until this pop up just fine I just don’t understand why my driver.find_element_by_xpath(‘<span class=“prod-desc”>Home (HO3)</span>’).click doesn’t work. I have a feeling the pop up menu is the reason behind it. I added time.sleep(5) to let the page load fully before I initiate the click but still nothing happens.

Comment: @Anonymous  I just don’t understand why my driver.find_element_by_xpath(‘<span class=“prod-desc”>Home (HO3)</span>’).click doesn’t work. I have a feeling the pop up menu is the reason behind it. I added time.sleep(5) to let the page load fully before I initiate the click but still nothing happens. Its tough to solve these things without people being able to test because of login.

Comment: This looks wrong. The Xpath syntax is quite specific. I would try something else. For example `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[text()="Home (HO3)"]').click()`. Can't guarantee this will work but you get the idea. If possible I would try to address tags by unique properties like by ID or class name if it's unique. Xpath is convenient when you can't provide a clear and stable identifier.

Comment: I have a question: are you running this code live on your machine or a server ? Do you **see** the browser window opening, doing the login and taking you where you expect ? You have to know how far your code arrives.

Comment: @Anonymous running code live with browser opening. Everything works up to this point, this pop up menu shows up and everything I try doesn’t work. All I have to do is click one of the options in the pop up and click start quote. I tried your Xpath code and it three codes that “By”isn’t defined. I can take more screenshots of the webpage and inspect elements if needed.

Comment: You need this dependency for `By`: `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`.

Comment: @Anonymous it actually worked thank you!!! It’s my first time posting on here and the help came almost immediately! However I anticipate something will come up again soon haha...but I’m making progress! Thanks again for the help.